# Toggle Nav Button Not Closing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nav

I have a three column layout inside of a horizontal nav menu. Everything works in desktop mode but when I shrink my browser to mobile display, the nav toggle button will open the menu but it won't toggle close the menu.

```
<nav>
<div class="navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height:1px;">
<div class="logo"><img src=""/></div>
<ul id="menu-header" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
<li id="menu-item-trending" class="menu-item-trending dropdown">
<a title="" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">TRENDING <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
  <li id="menu-item-trending" class="menu-item dropdown open">
    <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
      <div class="col-12 submenu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Pet Trends</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Hamster Trends</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Pet Care Trends</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Small Animal Trends</a></li>
      </div>
      <div class="container row-centered hidden-md">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 nopad"> 
            <!-- insert -->

            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 
              <!-- Indicators -->
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
              </ol>
              <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item"> <img class="first-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First slide">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                      <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item"> <img class="second-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Second slide">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                      <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                      <!--p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p--> 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item active"> <img class="third-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Third slide">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                      <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a> </div>
          </div>
          <!--end insert-->
          <div class="col-md-3 nopad">
            <div class="str-box clearfix">
              <div class="sect-title">Puppies</div>
            </div>
            <div class="str-box clearfix">
              <div class="sect-title">Adult Dogs</div>
            </div>
            <div class="str-box clearfix">
              <div class="sect-title">Dog Care</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="row secthdr">You might also like</div>
            <div class="row story-links">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ancillae singulis inciderint te sit, in primis expetendis referrentur mel. In cum prompta invidunt mediocritatem, ut adhuc nonumy voluptua eum.</div>
            <div class="row story-links">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ancillae singulis inciderint te s eum.</div>
            <div class="row story-links">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ancillae singulis inciderint te sit, in primis expetendis referrentur mel. In cum promptatua eum.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </li>
  </li>
</ul>
</li>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't included any CSS it might be a guess, but try opening your browser inspector (command + alt + i or F12) and see if your horizontal menu isn't taking place over your menu icon - after toggled.

Also, please add a working fiddle so it's easier for anyone to help you.